# How to use a variable in a module from the script that called the module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

I would like to make a plugin system for my script.

**How plugins are loaded**

The plugins are python modules stored in a specified folder.

I import the modules with this code:

```
class Igor:

    # ...

    def load_plugins(self):

        for file in os.listdir(self.plugins_folder):

            try:
                __import__(file)
            except Exception as error:
                sys.exit(error)

    # ...
```

**The variable I want to make available in the plugins**

I have a variable named `igor` who is an instance of `Igor`:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    # ...

    igor = Igor()

    # ...
```

**What I want the plugins developers able to do**

I want to make plugins development easy and `igor` have all the methods needed to make it easy.

At best it should be something like this (in `__init__.py`):

```
from plugins.files.files import Files

igor.register_plugin("files", Files())
```

**How can I do that?**

I really don't see how to do this `globals()` display `igor` in my main script but there is nothing in the globals from the menu (as expected from a module, it is sandboxed I supposed).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to change the load_plugins method on your Igor class:

```
    def load_plugins(self):
        if not os.path.exists(self.plugins_folder):
            os.makedirs(self.plugins_folder)

        plugin_folder_content = os.listdir(self.plugins_folder)

        for content in plugin_folder_content:
            content_path = os.path.join(self.plugins_folder, content)
            if os.path.isdir(content_path):
                plugin_entry_point_path = os.path.join(content_path, "__init__.py")
                if os.path.exists(plugin_entry_point_path):
                    try:
                         with open(plugin_entry_point_path, 'r') as file:
                             sys.path.insert(1, content_path)
                             exec(compile(file.read(), "script", "exec"), {"igor": self, "IgorPlugin": IgorPlugin, 'path': content_path})
                             sys.path.remove(content_path)
                    except Exception as exc:
                         sys.exit(exc)
```

This creates another problem: as we are excecuting the **init**.py files on each module, defined on each subdirectory, you can't import files easily, that's why I'm passing the path variable, to import files manually, this is an example of a imaginary **init**.py file which imports files.py plugin:

```
import os

files_path = os.path.join(path, "files.py")

exec(compile(open(files_path).read(), "script", "exec"), {"igor": igor, "IgorPlugin": IgorPlugin})
```

Comment: Thanks @avenet, but this is what I have for the moment, with a single class for each plugin. But I really want to have modules with __ini__.py and multiple files. My current code is available here : https://bitbucket.org/martin-damien/igor/src/07e27f489882878cf495b4183604d8322ed6904c/igor.py?at=master

Comment: Thanks for your advices @avenet. I see that there is no user friendly way to send variables for modules to other modules... I suppose that I will cotinue with simple files plugins for the moment.